# The data segment is not being initialized even though I did set an initial value to the variables

Tags: assembly, initialization, dos, x86-16, memory-segmentation

I have written a code that is supposed to make some sort of a list of numbers, but my data segment variables are not being initialized even though I did assign them an initial value?

This is how `DS:0000` looks when I run it:
[image: ds:0000]

This is my code, but the data segment just keeps the trash values:

```
MODEL small
STACK 100h

DATA SEGMENT
    size1 dw 0000h
    arr dw 20 dup(0000h)
DATA ENDS

CODE SEGMENT
ASSUME CS:CODE, DS:DATA

sidra_rekursivit proc
    mov bp, sp
    xor ax, ax
    mov ax, [bp+2]
    ; tnai azira
    cmp ax, 1
    je azira
    
    ; tempo
    mov cx, ax ; save ax
    shr ax, 1
    jnc zugi ; if zugi

    
izugi:  ; else
    mov ax, cx
    ;multiply by 3
    shl ax, 1
    add ax, cx
    ;end multiply
    ; add 1
    inc ax
    
    push ax
    call sidra_rekursivit
    jmp azira
    
zugi:
    push ax
    call sidra_rekursivit
    
azira:
    ; put the numbers in arr
    mov bx, [size1] ; arr size
    xor dx, dx ; clear dx
    mov dx, [bp+2] ; take the number from the stack
    mov word ptr arr[bx], dx ; put the number in the arr
    inc size1 ; increase the array posiotion
    ret 2
sidra_rekursivit endp

start:
;input
    mov ah, 1
    int 21h
    
    mov ah, 0
    sub al, 48
    mov dh, 10d
    mul dh
    mov dl, al
    
    mov ah, 1
    int 21h
    
    mov ah, 0
    sub al, 48
    add dl, al
    
; function call: stack push
    ; push input
    xor dh, dh
    push dx
    call sidra_rekursivit
    
exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
CODE ENDS
END start
```

Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: How are you building and linking this program?

Comment: You might need to manually set up `DS` with something like MOV AX, @DATA; MOV DS, AX`.  Not sure about the details as I don't know what assembler and toolchain you are programming for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When an .EXE program starts in the DOS environment, the `DS` segment register points at the ProgramSegmentPrefix PSP. That's what we see in the included screenshot.

`ASSUME DS:DATA` is merily an *indication* for the assembler so it can verify the addressability of data items. To actually make `DS` point to your `DATA SEGMENT`, you need code like `mov ax, @DATA` `mov ds, ax`. Put it where your code begins its execution.

```
start:
  mov ax, @DATA
  mov ds, ax
  ;input
  mov ah, 1
  int 21h
```

Not related, but your recursive procedure call will fail because either you don't preserve the `BP` register between calls, or you don't reload it from the `SP` register.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, it worked!

Comment: (And if you need ES also set to the same segment base, e.g. for `rep movsb`, use `mov es, ax`)